# speed up Excel off-sheet dependents search

Tags: vba, excel

I've incorporated the off-sheet dependents search using the "ShowDependents" and "NavigateArrow" VBA methods. Everything works well but it is just painfully slow (for a large number of dependents). 
Are there alternatives, way to speed it up? I've tried disabling the ScreenUpdating but that doesn't speed it up by much.
This is what my code is based on: http://www.technicana.com/vba-for-checking-dependencies-on-another-sheet

Comment: If there is a logic behind your dependencies then perhaps you don't have to find them all, but only a few and calculate the rest from them. I think that could save you a lot of time.

Comment: here you can find some good tips to sped-up your code  http://www.excelitems.com/2010/12/optimize-vba-code-for-faster-macros.html

Comment: Have you disabled output to the Immediate Window? This is the bottleneck. To agregate dependants, use another data structure like `Collection` or even VBA Array. If you need more than one field in a collection item, create a `Class Module`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following function which is supposed to return true if the cell you pass it has a direct dependent on a different sheet:

```
Function LeadsOut(c As Range) As Boolean
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i As Long, target As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    c.ShowDependents

    On Error GoTo return_false
    i = 1
    Do While True
        Set target = c.NavigateArrow(False, i)
        If c.Parent.Name <> target.Parent.Name Then
            ws.Select
            ActiveSheet.ClearArrows
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            LeadsOut = True
            Exit Function
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
return_false:
    LeadsOut = False
    ActiveSheet.ClearArrows
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function

Sub test()
    MsgBox LeadsOut(Selection)
End Sub
```

To test it, I linked the test sub to a command button on Sheet1.

In A2 I entered the formula `= A1 + 1`, with no other formulas on Sheet1.

On Sheet2 I entered the formula `=Sheet1!A2`.

Back on Sheet1, if I select A2 and invoke the sub it almost instantly pops up "True". But if I select A1 and invoke the sub it returns "False" -- but only after a delay of several seconds.

To debug it, I put a `Debug.Print i` right before `i = i + 1` in the loop. The Immediate Window, after running it again, looks like:

```
32764 
32765 
32766 
32767
```

Weird!!!!! 
I was utterly stumped until I replaced `Debug.Print i` by

```
Debug.Print target.Address(External:=True)
```

Which led to output that looks ends like:

```
[dependents.xlsm]Sheet1!$A$1
[dependents.xlsm]Sheet1!$A$1
[dependents.xlsm]Sheet1!$A$1
[dependents.xlsm]Sheet1!$A$1
```

`NavigateArrow(False,i)` goes back to the originating cell and stays there once i exceeds the number of dependents! This is seemingly undocumented and massively annoying. The code you linked to was written by someone who hasn't discovered this. As a kludge, you should check that when you are navigating arrows you haven't returned to the starting point. The following seems to work almost instantly in all cases, although I haven't tested it very much:

```
Function LeadsOut(c As Range) As Boolean
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i As Long, target As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    c.ShowDependents

    On Error GoTo return_false
    i = 1
    Do While True
        Set target = c.NavigateArrow(False, i)
        If target.Address(External:=True) = c.Address(External:=True) Then
            GoTo return_false
        End If
        If c.Parent.Name <> target.Parent.Name Then
            ws.Select
            ActiveSheet.ClearArrows
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            LeadsOut = True
            Exit Function
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
return_false:
    LeadsOut = False
    ActiveSheet.ClearArrows
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

The key lines are the three lines which begin

```
If target.Address(External:=True) = c.Address(External:=True)
```

Adding some such check in the sub you linked to should make a massive difference.